# White TFT LCD touchscreen isn't functioning on Raspbian or Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, ubuntu

I finally received my 3.5" KeDei 480x320 16bit/18bit version 3.0 TFT LCD  touchscreen from Hong Kong. It only connects through the GPIO pins. I plugged it into my Raspberry Pi 2 and I was met with a white screen when I tried both the Ubuntu and Raspbian images.

I have updated Raspbian, I know that my good power supply is good, and I tried enabling the SPI kernel module through the Raspberry Pi Configuration GUI since the touchscreen says that it connects via SPI. The only thing that I think could be wrong now is that the drivers are not installed or that I don't have the right kernel.

If I can get the touchscreen to function on either the Ubuntu or the Raspbian image, then I will just take the one that works. Though if both could work flawlessly I think I would prefer using the Ubuntu image since I am more familiar with it.

backside of the touchscreen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B50TnhMx_VOccnBrOHBhb2lMUG8/view?usp=sharing
product page:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5-Raspberry-Pi-2-B-B-A-Touch-Screen-Monitor-480x320-LCD-with-Case-Adapter-/252070076743?hash=item3ab08c2147:g:sGUAAOSw~gRV3Ypw

Comment: What TFT they are not all the same, What does the documentation that came with it say? Is it designed to connect via I2C or spi , or via a different format (it is usually one or the other not both). You mention a ribbon cable most small TFT's I have seen for the Pi connect directly to the GPIO pins without a cable.  Can we see a photo of the connections. Please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the touchscreen did not come with any documentation so it was a bit difficult to be specific. I am not sure how the part about the ribbon cable got included, especially since there is no ribbon cable. I did add in some more details as best as I could. Hopefully those details will be enough because I can't be any more specific about it. I have said all that I know.

Comment: Please add pics and a link to the product page otherwise I am not sure how much help we can be.

Comment: Youu may want to read through this thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=124961

Comment: especially the last post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen is finally functioning! This link had the screen drivers: https://mega.nz/#!hhdCTCDZ!UXyyh17uZo3p0O95mNmkGrWjmCv7NUEaofx9-zqoGj0

Backup link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B50TnhMx_VOcY2RuQnpSYjZsOEk/view?usp=sharing

After downloading the drivers, I ran the script that came with the .zip file, rebooted, and everything worked well.

To update the system:

sudo apt-mark hold raspberrypi-bootloader

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Is this mega-link really persistent? Without a second source a broken link would render this answer almost useless.

Comment: The link goes to a cloud storage website. I suppose that in theory the person whom put the .zip file on it could remove it any time they want and thus break the link. In most cases the manufacturer would provide the customer with the touchscreen drivers or a way to get them, yet mine did not. I did a Google Search, yet I could not find a second source. The manufacturer is Chinese, so one might have to search with Chinese characters, which I am not skilled at. But just in case the link breaks, I am going to upload a link to a copy of it to a different cloud storage account as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same screen:

http://heikki.virekunnas.fi/2015/raspberry-pi-tft/

I found that by searching "kedei touchscreen".  In a comment elsewhere I mentioned [this list](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/touchscreen/Kconfig) to you of touchscreen drivers available in the vanilla kernel (most of which are not precompiled for the pi).  Turns out there is [a pile more in `staging/fbtft`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/fbtft/Kconfig), most or all of which do appear to be [precompiled with the pi kernel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/modules/4.1.15%2B/kernel/drivers/staging/fbtft).

If that page is correct, the driver might be `fb_ili93421.ko` -- notice the `fb_` prefix which is not used on that page. He refers to something in `video/fbdev` from an out-of-tree source, I would try this one first.

```
sudo modprobe fb_ili93421
```

And see if anything happens.  If there's nothing obvious, check `ls /dev | grep "^fb"`; if there are two devices, 0, and 1, the driver may be working.

Comment: I tried following the procedure found inside of the first link. I must have done something weird; the keyboard and mouse would not function at all when the pi was booted into the alternative kernel and the screen was still white... If I had to guess, I think that when I was copying the folder contents, I somehow deleted the mouse and keyboard drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to download the right driver for your screen, I made the mistake of downloading the one that looked more "recent", but you need to check your LCD display in the back and look for the right version.

After that just follow this:
Copy the file using sftp to root

then use putty:

```
tar zxf LCD_show_v5.tar.gz
sudo ./LCD_backup
sudo ./LCD35_v5
```

Answer (score -1):

http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html

Found this yesterday downloaded it over night so very slow but the image worked my Kedei 3.5" V5 touch screen it working and looks super cool LOL !

Cheers

PB

Comment: A little more detail is required link only answers are not acceptable

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @DarthVader It is not that they are unacceptable (which is not a friendly word choice - it is rather judgmental) It is that they are low quality and subject to link rot.